# Auto Increment Sequence in NestJs/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-sequence

I'm migrating a NodeJs project to NestJs, this project uses MongoDB as back-end database and Mongoose as ODM. I was using the [mongoose-sequence](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence) plugin to handle autoincrement sequences, however I'm facing troubles requiring the library under NestJs.

The mongoose-sequence documentation explains how to import the library using CommonJS syntax as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrementFactory = require('mongoose-sequence');

const connection = await mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://...');

const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection);
```

Using ES6 import syntax it would be something like:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as AutoIncrementFactory from 'mongoose-sequence';

const connection = ...;

const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection);
```

However since NestJs uses Dependency Injection, accessing the native connection is not so direct. According to the [documentation to integrate MongoDB using Mongoose](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb?source=post_page-----930a1d38a0a8----------------------#connection) accessing the native Mongoose Connection object can be done using the `@InjectConnection()` decorator as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

But since [TypeScript decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) can only be attached to a class declaration, method, accessor, property, or parameter I don't see how to inject the connection, require the plugin and initialize it on my Schema classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to register a plugin for a given schema using the `forFeatureAsync()` method of the `MongooseModule` along with a factory provider (i.e., `useFactory`).

Following the example from the [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb):

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: Cat.name,
        useFactory: () => {
          const schema = CatsSchema;
          schema.plugin(require('mongoose-autopopulate'));
          return schema;
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However with the `mongoose-sequence` plugin it's necessary to pass the native Mongoose connection object to the plugin initialization. This can be achieved by injecting the connection into the factory provider with the `getConnectionToken` method:

```
import {getConnectionToken, MongooseModule} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as AutoIncrementFactory from 'mongoose-sequence';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: Cat.name,
        useFactory: async (connection: Connection) => {
          const schema = CatsSchema;
          const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection);
          schema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {inc_field: 'id'});
          return schema;
        },
        inject: [getConnectionToken('YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME')],
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I'm trying to use this but I'm getting typscript errors from AutoIncrementFactory(connection). "Argument of type Connection is not assignable to parameter of type 'Schema<any>'.  Did you run into this as well?

Comment: Hi @Todd, no I didn't encounter that problem, it seems to me you are assigning the connection to something that is not a Connection, but without more context it's difficult to tell.

Comment: thanks Andres.  My module looks just like yours above.  Maybe underlying libraries differ between our installations.

Comment: I did the same implementation explained in this answer, however when I generate a new orderModel, the orderId field doesn't populate.

Comment: Ok I fixed by doing this forFeatureAsync import on the main AppModule and not on the OrderModule. It's finally working.

Comment: @AndresFelipe Getting this error any idea? `Cannot read property 'modelNames' of undefined`

Comment: @HenonoaH Same here, did you solve it?

Comment: const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection as any); 
i will fix the above issues

Comment: can you guys share a complete example? I'm following the sample in the database `counter` collection automatically created, but the user collection doesn't have id automatically generated, and no error

Thanks! @AndresFelipe  @Todd

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem but this worked for me:

```
MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
  {
    name: Cats.name,
    useFactory: async (connection: Connection) => {
      const schema = CatsSchema;
      const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(connection);
      schema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {inc_field: 'id'});
      return schema;
    },
    inject: [getConnectionToken()],
  },
]),
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem and it worked for me from the first time

```
@Module({
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
        {
            name: Supplier.name,
            useFactory: async (connection: Connection) =>{
                const schema = SupplierSchema;
                const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(connection)
                 schema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {inc_field: 'code'});
                 return schema;
            },
            inject: [getConnectionToken(process.env.DATA_BASE_URI)]
        }
    ])],
    controllers: [SupplierController],
    providers: [SupplierService]

})
```

but a simple questions : why would i use async when i don't have any await ?

Answer (score 0):

At this time 2023 Sept, `mongoose-sequence` does not work with mongoose 7
refer to this [issue](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence/issues/133)

> it does not work with mongoose 7. Schema.create hangs. seems to be related to callbacks being deprecated.

However there is a new package `@typegoose/auto-increment` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typegoose/auto-increment

```bash
npm i @typegoose/auto-increment
```

### How to use

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule, getConnectionToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from './model/user.model';
import { UsersController } from './controller/users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './service/Users.service';
import {
  AutoIncrementID,
  AutoIncrementIDOptions,
} from '@typegoose/auto-increment';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: User.name,
        useFactory: async () => {
          const schema = UserSchema;

          schema.plugin(AutoIncrementID, {
            field: 'numbering',
            startAt: 1,
          } satisfies AutoIncrementIDOptions);

          return schema;
        },
        inject: [getConnectionToken()],
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```