# NestJS and Mongoose Using Mongoose-Sequence

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-sequence

I am attempting to utilize the plugin 'mongoose-sequence' with my NestJS application.  I wish for this plugin to be useable by all the modules I will be creating for this application.  Here's my app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UsersModule } from './user/user.module';
import AutoIncrementFactory from 'mongoose-sequence';

const mongoUri = 'mongodb://localhost/apptest';
const connName = 'apptest';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(mongoUri, {
      connectionName: connName,
      useFindAndModify: false, 
      connectionFactory: (connection, connName) => {
        const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection);
        connection.plugin(AutoIncrement);
        return connection;
      }),
      UserModule,
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
});
export class AppModule {}
```

When I start the server, I get the following error message:

```
Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:48 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:48 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +35ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:48 AM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:48 AM   [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:48 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:51 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)... +3005ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:54 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)... +3006ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:38:57 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)... +3007ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:39:00 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)... +3007ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:39:03 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)... +3006ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:39:06 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (7)... +3006ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:39:09 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (8)... +3003ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:39:12 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)... +3005ms
[Nest] 372   - 07/21/2020, 11:39:12 AM   [ExceptionHandler] mongoose_sequence_1.default is not a function +1ms
TypeError: mongoose_sequence_1.default is not a function
    at connectionFactory (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/dist/app.module.js:31:70)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:59:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:16:12)
    at /Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:58:49
    at Observable._subscribe (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/observable/defer.js:10:21)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at RetryWhenSubscriber.notifyNext (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/retryWhen.js:85:21)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at Notification.observe (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Notification.js:22:50)
    at AsyncAction.DelaySubscriber.dispatch (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/delay.js:54:40)
    at AsyncAction._execute (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/rxjs/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js:71:18)
```

Any ideas, why plugin is unable to connect to the mongodb?  The mongodb is running and I connect to it via mongo client, and when I remove the `const AutoIncrement...` and the `connection.plugin(...` lines.

UPDATE:
Changing the import of the AutoIncrementFactory to:
`import AutoIncrementFactory = require('mongoose-sequence');`
produces an maximum call stat size exceeded:

UPDATE 2: made recommended change below, and same error.

```
[Nest] 68822   - 07/22/2020, 9:12:20 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 68822   - 07/22/2020, 9:12:20 AM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +30ms
[Nest] 68822   - 07/22/2020, 9:12:20 AM   [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 68822   - 07/22/2020, 9:12:20 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 68822   - 07/22/2020, 9:12:20 AM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseCoreModule dependencies initialized +11ms
[Nest] 68822   - 07/22/2020, 9:12:21 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Maximum call stack size exceeded +310ms
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.clone (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/clone.js:53:16)
    at Schema.path (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:678:24)
    at Schema.add (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:519:14)
    at new Schema (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:130:10)
    at Mongoose.Schema (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:95:12)
    at SequenceFactory.Sequence._createCounterModel (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose-sequence/lib/sequence.js:170:36)
    at SequenceFactory.Sequence.enable (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose-sequence/lib/sequence.js:103:31)
    at SequenceFactory.Sequence.getInstance (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose-sequence/lib/sequence.js:92:14)
    at Schema.plugin (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:1500:3)
    at applyPlugins (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/schema/applyPlugins.js:11:14)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.model (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:1070:5)
    at SequenceFactory.Sequence._createCounterModel (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose-sequence/lib/sequence.js:191:23)
    at SequenceFactory.Sequence.enable (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose-sequence/lib/sequence.js:103:31)
    at SequenceFactory.Sequence.getInstance (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose-sequence/lib/sequence.js:92:14)
    at Schema.plugin (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:1500:3)
    at applyPlugins (/Users/tbruner/dev/s4n3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/schema/applyPlugins.js:11:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose-sequence is not an ES6 module.
In the first version you're using import and in the second you're mixing `import` and `require` which is not allowed.
You should try with

```
const AutoIncrementFactory = require('mongoose-sequence');
```

Comment: Made the suggested change and I get the Maximum call stack size exceeded error just as before.

Comment: I have the same issue, I tried also the solution provided here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824276/auto-increment-sequence-in-nestjs-mongoose

but when i generate a new model, the orderId doesn't populate.